Can I override a variable passed from the CLI to Make from within the Makefile?
If I call a makefile as make target TARGET_VERSION=""
And within the makefile I have this logic right at the beginning to update the variable would it work or would the value from the command take precedence?
ifeq ($(strip $(TARGET_VERSION)),)
# Go to BUILDROOT/PACKAGES and find the latest version
$(info Target Version not provided. Finding the latest version in $(BUILDROOT)/$(PACKAGES))
$(eval TARGET_VERSION=$(shell ls -1 $(BUILDROOT)/$(PACKAGES) | sort -Vr | head -1))
$(info Latest version found is $(TARGET_VERSION))
endif 

When I ran make target, the TARGET_VERSION got picked up and set.
When I ran make target TARGET_VERSION="", it did go into the if block but did not override the variable.
Why do this? This make target is to be called from a parent Makefile where I would like to have the option to set the TARGET_VERSION or not. I'm expecting this child Makefile to just pickup the latest version if I don’t set it. Since I have multiple targets in the parent which call different targets within this child Makefile it wouldn't be clean to conditionally include the param or not...
Any help would be appreciated.

Strange, why are you using eval here?
$(eval TARGET_VERSION=$(shell ls -1 $(BUILDROOT)/$(PACKAGES) | sort -Vr | head -1))

Why not just write the assignment directly, using :=?
TARGET_VERSION := $(shell ls -1 $(BUILDROOT)/$(PACKAGES) | sort -Vr | head -1)

Command line overrides always take precedence over variables in the makefile; this is well documented in the manual.
You can use the override directive to prevent this.
However, I recommend you choose a different method.  For example, separate the variable that users might override on the command line from the one used internally.
